# Variable height items in Win32 ListView

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, winapi

Is it possible to have variable size (owner draw) items in the Win32 ListView, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [WM_MEASUREITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775925%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: ListView controls do not support WM_MEASUREITEM, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use Listbox with LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE style for supporting items with variable height. Then Listbox will send WM_MEASUREITEM for each item.